# CAN bus TVS diode/EMI for motorcycle

Tags: can

[image: CAN bus TVS schematic]

I am motorcycle engineer, I don't know much about CAN bus systems, and I need your advice.

I had searched on this site, and I found this schematic. But in my country, I can't find the components like this. Could I use two 1N4148 opposite to replace them? And do I have to install it on every node (Dashboard, ECU, ABS, and BBS) to protect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [NUP2105](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NUP2105L-D.PDF). The 120 ohm termination resistor is only for the two last nodes on the bus. It reduces the reflections on the line. The common mode choke is optional and is rarely used.

The purpose of the TVS diode is protect the transceiver against a harmful overvoltage condition. Each node needs one. The purpose of the common mode choke is to block noise.

By default I always galvanically isolate the CAN bus, using [ISO1050](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso1050.pdf) and [SN6501](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn6501.pdf).

Kvaser has [a short tutorial](https://www.kvaser.com/can-protocol-tutorial/) on CAN bus. I suggest you read it.

Comment: I'd say that the common mode choke is more common than the TVS diodes. The transceiver is going to be pretty rugged in itself and can handle some transients.

Comment: I very thank all of you for quick reply. So finally I will built a kit (nup2105l + common mode choke) by myself. BUT will I install one for dashboard, another for ECU ? Or I just need ONE for all system ?

Comment: @LêTrung each node needs this. I've edited the anwser.

Comment: The choke is definetely normaly used, even more in automotive applications where spark noises are all over the place

Answer (score 0):

The diodes are transient voltage suppressors (TVS diodes). You cannot replace them by any other kind of diode. If you don't know the difference between a TVS diode and a 1N4148, then you shouldn't meddle with them in the first place.

If your system is using 12V then you should put TVS diodes of roughly 16V there. Following the recommendations by [this ON Semi app note](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8169-D.PDF), you could use diodes such as NUP2105L or LC03−6R2.

Comment: I got it. Very very thank you ! I think I can save my bike about "Lost communication" (I got this problem many times cause CAN transceiver fault)